# Node zlib.gzip returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm running this code in Node and for some reason when I result result it give undefined but when I console log it result is not undefined and I am really confused as to why:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

function gzip(data) {
  zlib.gzip(data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return err;
    console.log(result, data);
    return result;
  });
}

console.log(gzip('hello'));
```

console.log results

```
Info: Start process (8:31:38 PM)
undefined
Results: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a cb 48 cd c9 c9 07 00 86 a6 10 36 05 00 00 00> Data: hello
Info: End process (8:31:38 PM)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is first logged because your function named gzip (`function gzip(data) { ... }`) does not return anything.

In attempt to help with the confusion, I'm betting the return statements in your callback function (`(err, result) => { ... }`) are not behaving as expected.  The return statements in your callback function are not returning the value to you in a way that you could log. I recommend reading the node.js guide on [callback functions](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) to learn how they are used with asynchronous functions like [`zlib.gzip()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gzip_buffer_options_callback).

You might want to checkout the synchronous version, [`zlib.gzipSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gzipsync_buffer_options), as it may behave closer to your expectations right now. I also recommend reading the node.js guide [Overview of Blocking vs Non-Blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) to learn about the differences between these kinds of synchronous and asynchronous functions in general.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. When I called the function as a call back it gets added to the blocking thread. So when console.log() runs there is no value and it returns undefined, then the callback runs and returns the value. That is why the return is out of order. So I think it was that I was looking it as a Sync process and that is why my expectations were off and why zlib.gzipSync() will fall inline with the Sync mindset I was looking at the code with. At least that is what I got from it. Either way thanks again!